# How to compress numpy arrays before inserting into LMDB dataset?

Tags: numpy, lmdb

I have size of [82,3,780,1024] tensors - merge of 82 different image frames - in uint8 format. LMDB goes wild in terms of size, once i start to insert these. Is there any way to compress these tensors before inserting?

For inserting I follow the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266384/write-numpy-arrays-to-lmdb)

I find a solution with `cv2.encode` and `cv2.decode` but it is not applicable to such tensors afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the many fast in-memory compression algorithms. One very good option would be to use [blosc](http://blosc.org/) library, which itself allows you to use quite a few algorithms specialized (or performing well) in this scenarios.

You can get the list of supported compression algorithms by invoking (in blosc version 1.4.4)

```
import blosc
blosc.compressor_list()
['blosclz', 'lz4', 'lz4hc', 'snappy', 'zlib', 'zstd']
```

and you can compress/decompress any binary data or string using the usual `blosc.compress(bytesobj, typesize=8, clevel=9, shuffle=1, cname='blosclz')` and `blosc.decompress(bytesobj)` methods.

I typically use one of `blosc` variants if I need speed, and `bz2` library if I want very good compression ratios (but slower run time).